# Why my custom directive does not appear in my vue element?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

In my App?vue template , I have a custom directive ( **v-noise** )

**//App.vue**

```
<template>
 <div id="app" class="container" v-noise="'brown'">
 <...>
 </div>
</template>
```

Testing my plugin, I don't see the directive in the console.log

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from '@/App'
    import VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin from '@/plugins/VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin'

    import sinon from 'sinon'
    import { mount } from 'avoriaz'

    Vue.use(VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin)
    ...

    describe('VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin', () => {
      let wrapper
      let audioContext = sinon.mock(new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)())

      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(App)
      })

      it('should start noise', () => {
        console.log('WRAPPER.VM.$EL: ', wrapper.vm.$el)
        Vue.noise.start()
        audioContext.expects('resume').once()
      })
    })
```

no v-noise directive

```
'WRAPPER.VM.$EL: ', <div data-v-ee77fb84="" id="app" class="container">
 <h2 data-v-ee77fb84=""><span data-v-ee77fb84="">POMODORO </span> 
<span data-v-c15acdbe="" data-v-ee77fb84=""><button data-v-c15acdbe="">
....
```

I want to be able to change the directive (changing the colour of the noise )
feedback welcome

Comment: Directives are not rendered. They are not DOM constructs. They are part of the template that gets compiled into the render function.

Comment: OK thanks a lt .. I've forgotten it ... I need to modify this code and bind a data object to it in order to be able to change the colour of the noise..